# Angular 7 router transition animation triggered by scroll

Tags: angular, animation, transition, router

There is an application inwhich there are three simple component. I would like switch between the components by scrolling with route trasition animation.

The animation would be that the first component slide up and out, and a second component slide in from bottom. I know it's very similar to a simple webpage with anchors and scrolling up and down, but I would like to make this angular implementation.

I couldn't find any solution for now. Any idea of somebody?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think you can use `scroll-behavior: smooth;` css rule to a smooth scroll transition, if your components is on one page, and you have anchors. But with this option you need configurate the `RouterModule.forRoot()` with an extra config option, `anchorScrolling: 'enabled'`.